# Why is the response sometimes passing through and sometimes not when using requests httpx in python?

Tags: python, httpx

I am trying to scrape this website items, however when I used httpx or even requests sometimes it passes and gets the response sometimes it doesn't. It seems random, that's why I tried doing a rerun of the failed items to get the results. However this does not seem to work 100% of all the time. Is there something that I am not doing right? Can somebody help?

Below is a sample of the web I am scraping, if it does not show any errors you can loop it to scrape the same thing twice.

Here's my current code:

```
urllist=['https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-16912/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-16912-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-04124/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-04124-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-19598/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-19598-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-01115/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-01115-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3206709&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-02620/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-02620-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-17552/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-17552-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3023611&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-08377/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-08377-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-03274/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-03274-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3069769&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-04345/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-04345-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-01030/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-01030-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&cnc=false',
'https://www.blibli.com/backend/product-detail/products/ps--RAM-70107-01534/_summary?defaultItemSku=RAM-70107-01534-00001&pickupPointCode=PP-3239816&cnc=false']

rancherrors=pd.DataFrame()
ranchdf=pd.DataFrame()
    for url in urllist:
     try:   
            ua = UserAgent()
            USER_AGENT = ua.random
            headers={
                "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "accept-language": "id-ID,id;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
                "cache-control": "max-age=0",
                "sec-ch-ua": 'Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99',
                "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
                "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
                "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
                "sec-fetch-site": "none",
                'X-Forwarded-For': f'{random_ip}',
                "user-agent" : f"{USER_AGENT}",
                'referer':'https://www.blibli.com/'
                }
            response =httpx.get(url,headers=headers)

        try:
            price=str(response.json()['data']['price']['listed']).replace(".0","")
            discount=str(response.json()['data']['price']['totalDiscount'])
        except:
            price="0"
            discount="0"
        try:
            unit=str(response.json()['data']['uniqueSellingPoint']).replace("• ","")
        except:
            unit=""

        dat={
            'product_name':response.json()['data']['name'],
            'normal_price':price,
            'discount':discount,
            'competitor_id':response.json()['data']['ean'],
            'url':input,
            'unit':unit,
            'astro_id':id,
            'date_key':today,
            'web':'ranch market'
            }
        dat=pd.DataFrame([dat])
        ranchdf=ranchdf.append(dat)
        sleep(randint(2,5))
    except Exception as e:
        datum={
            'id':id,
            'url':url
        }
        datum=pd.DataFrame([datum])
        rancherrors=rancherrors.append(datum)
        print(f'{url} error {e}')
```

Comment: _sometimes it passes and gets the response sometimes it doesn't_ What, exactly, do you mean?  Surely it always gets **some** response.  Do you mean that you expect some specific element in the response, and sometimes that element is missing?  If so, what does the response contain in that case?

Comment: Just as a guess, the website might have decided that you are a spammer and is refusing to serve your requests for some brief time.

Comment: i get denied access after checking, however hard I tried to extend the sleep radint it still is the same. Is there a way around this? I've tried using rotate user agent and supplied a random-ip. is there a way around this ?